# Subtract today's date from date field

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

In SSRS, I'm trying to build a calculated field that will calculate the number of days that have elapsed between a date field in my report and today.

I've tried `=DateDiff("d",Fields!dts.Value,Today())`

Comment: Could you [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/57382714/edit) your question to include the expression you've tried?

Comment: @MarkB have you tried DateAdd expression in ReportBuilder

Comment: @CR241 He would be looking to use `DateDiff`, not `DateAdd`.

Comment: @Steve-o169 I've tried =DateDiff("d",Fields!dts.Value,Today())

Comment: @MarkB, did you try putting `Today()` first and `Fields!dts.Value` second?  Also, you may want to verify that `dts` is a date datatype.  Also, what error is occurring?

Comment: Try adding this as a column in your SQL query instead of having the report calculate it row-by-row.

Comment: @Steve-o169, yes, I did try that.  No matter what place I put the 'Today()' is shows that I have a syntax error between the ()

Comment: @RussellFox, thanks.....that worked!